# loop back to a menu when using a return statement?

Tags: python-3.x

I am adding up all the values in a text file and using a return statement to display the value at the end, I am also using that value in another function. So basically I have a function that calls another function.

My problem is that I need to ask the user if they want to go back to the menu again but I can't do that when using a return statement but if I don't use a return statement then I can get the total to go into my other function.

The average_salary function is the one that calls the total_salary function so that it can get the total value.

My code :

```
with open("Records.txt") as file:  # Opens the text file with all the records in it
    records = [line.strip() for line in file if not line.startswith("#")]  # Creates a list named Records and stores all the records ignoring any lines with a '#'


def main():
    print("\nSelect from one of the options below:\n")  # Asks the user to select one of the options on the menu
    print("Enter '1' to print out the number of records"  # Tells the user what will happen if they select 1
          "\nEnter '2' to display a list of employees and their respective details"  # Tells the user what will happen if they select 2
          "\nEnter '3' to display the total salary bill"  # Tells the user what will happen if they select 3
          "\nEnter '4' to display a report showing the average salary based on the amount of employees"  # Tells the user what will happen if they select 4
          "\nEnter '5' to add a new employee to the list"  # Tells the user what will happen if they select 5
          "\nEnter '6' to display a report to show the amount of employees that are in each position type"  # Tells the user what will happen if they select 6
          "\nEnter '7' to display employees who earn a higher salary than the threshold"  # Tells the user what will happen if they select 7
          "\nEnter '8' to search for an existing record"  # Tells the user what will happen if they select 8
          "\nEnter '9' to exit the program\n")  # Tells the user what will happen if they select 9

    user_choice = input("Please enter the number of the option you would like use: ")  # Asks the user to select what they would to do with the program from a selection of options

    if user_choice == "1":  # Checks to see if the user has entered '1', if the user enters '1' then the code inside this IF Statement will execute
        number_of_lines()  # Call the number_of_lines function

    elif user_choice == "2":  # Checks to see if the user has entered '2', if the user enters '2' then the code inside this IF Statement will execute
        list_of_employees()  # Calls the list_of_employees function

    elif user_choice == "3":  # Checks to see if the user has entered '3', if the user enters '3' then the code inside this IF Statement will execute
        print("\nYour salary total is £", format(total_salary(), ",.2f"), sep='')  # calls the total_salary function and separates it with a space

    elif user_choice == "4":  # Checks to see if the user has entered '4', if the user enters '4' then the code inside this IF Statement will execute
        average_salary()  # Calls the average_salary function

    elif user_choice == "5":  # Checks to see if the user has entered '5', if the user enters '5' then the code inside this IF Statement will execute
        add_new_employee()  # Calls the add_new_employee function

    elif user_choice == "6":  # Checks to see if the user has entered '6', if the user enters '6' then the code inside this IF Statement will execute
        number_of_position_type()  # Calls the number_of_position_type function

    elif user_choice == "7":  # Checks to see if the user has entered '7', if the user enters '7' then the code inside this IF Statement will execute
        above_salary_threshold()  # Calls the above_user_threshold function

    elif user_choice == "8":  # Checks to see if the user has entered '8', if the user enters '8' then the code inside this IF Statement will execute
        search_for_a_record()  # Calls the add_new_employee function

    elif user_choice == "9":  # Checks to see if the user has entered '9', if the user enters '9' then the code inside this IF Statement will execute
        print("\nProgram closed successfully")  # Prints a message to the user
        exit()  # Exits the program

    else:
        print("\nEnter a number between 1 to 9")  # Displays a message to the user if the do not select one of the above options
        main()

# End of IF Statement


def number_of_lines():  # Creates a function named 'number_of_lines'
    records_count = sum(1 for records_count in open("Records.txt") if not records_count.startswith("#"))  # converts the record_count to a sum and calculates the number of lines in the records.txt file, ignoring the commented lines
    print("\nThe number of records is:", records_count)  # Prints the number of records for the user to see
    lines_finished = input("\nAre you ready to return back to the menu?(yes/no): ").lower()  # Asks the user for input
    if lines_finished == 'yes':  # Checks the users input to see if it is 'yes' , if the users input matches the condition then the code inside the IF will run
        main()  # Returns the user to the main function
    else:
        number_of_lines()  # If the user types anything but yes then the number_of_lines function will run


def list_of_employees():  # Creates a function named 'list_of_employees'
    for line in open("Records.txt"):  # Opens the records text file
        li = line.strip()  # Remove any unnecessary spaces
        if not li.startswith("#"):  # removes any lines that start with a '#'
            print(line.rstrip())  # prints the records to the user
    employees_finished = input("\nAre you ready to return back to the menu?(yes/no): ").lower()
    if employees_finished == 'yes':  # Checks if the users input is equal to yes
        main()  # Returns the user to the main function
    else:
        list_of_employees()  # If the user types anything but yes then the list_of_employees function will run


def total_salary():  # Creates a function named 'total_salary'
    with open("Records.txt", "r") as record_file:  # Opens the records files as read and creates a variable called record_file
        salaries_list = (record_file.read().split()[11::7])  # Creates a variable named salaries_list, the records files is then read in and split. I then tell the program to start on index 11 and to skip the next 7 elements, this happens until the loop is over
        salaries = ' '.join(salaries_list)  # joins all values into a list
        salaries = salaries.replace(',', '')  # Replaces all the ',' with spaces
        salaries = salaries.split()  # Puts all the salaries into a list again
        total = 0  # creates a variable called total
        for i in salaries:  # Creates a for loop to loop the salaries and add them all together
            total += int(i)  # Increments by one every time adding all the salaries together
        return total  # returns the total value


def average_salary():  # Creates a function named 'average_salary'
    record_count = sum(1 for record in open("Records.txt") if not record.startswith("#"))  # converts the record_count to a sum and calculates the number of lines in the records.txt file
    print("\nThe amount of employees is:", record_count)  # Prints out the number of records and takes away one to take away the heading line inside the text file
    salary = total_salary()  # Calls the total_salary() function
    print("\nThe total salary is: £", format(salary, ",.2f"))
    print("\nThe average salary is: £", format(salary / record_count, ".2f"))  # Takes the total salary bill and divides it by the amount of lines and formats it to 2 decimal places
    average_salary_finished = input("\nAre you ready to return back to the menu?(yes/no): ").lower()  # Stores the users input into the average_salary_finished variable and converts it to lowercase
    if average_salary_finished == 'yes':  # Checks if the users input is equal to yes
        main()  # Returns the user to the main function
    else:
        average_salary()  # If the user types anything but yes then the average_salary function will run


def add_new_employee():  # Creates a function named 'add_new_employee'
    with open("records.txt", "a+") as storing_records:  # Opens the record text file for append+ so that anything written to the text file will be written to the end and also I can read the file
        last_record = records[-1]  # Creates a variable called last_record and stores the values of the records variable inside, then it gets the last value in the list.
        print("\nThe last record in the file is:\n" + last_record, "\n" + "\nPlease enter the number that comes after the previous user ID")  # Prints the last_record variable
        another_record = "y"  # Creates a variable called another_Record and sets it to 'y'
        while another_record == "y" or another_record == "Y":  # Creates a while loop that will keep running as long as the another_Record variable is set to 'y' or 'Y'
            employee_number = input("\nEnter your employee number:")  # Stores the users input in the employee_number variable
            employee_name = input("\nEnter your name:")  # Stores the users input in the employee_name variable
            employee_age = input("\nEnter your age:")  # Stores the users input in the employee_age variable
            employee_position = input("\nEnter your position:")  # Stores the users input in the employee_position variable
            employee_salary = input("\nEnter your salary:")  # Stores the users input in the employee_salary variable
            employee_years = input("\nEnter the amount of years you have been employed:")  # Stores the users input in the employee_years variable
            user_input_record = employee_number + ', ' + employee_name + ', ' + employee_age + ', ' + employee_position + ', ' + employee_salary + ', ' + employee_years  # Adds all the user inputs together and separates them with comas
            storing_records.write(user_input_record + "\n")  # Stores the user input in the records text file
            another_record = input("\nDo you want to input another record? (yes/no): ").lower()  # Asks the user if they want to add another record, if the user types 'y' or 'Y' then the while loops will run again
    if another_record == 'yes':
        add_new_employee()  # If the user types anything but yes then the add_new_employee function will run
    else:
        main()  # Returns the user to the main function


def number_of_position_type():  # Creates a function called number_of_position_type
    with open("Records.txt", "r") as record:  # Reads in the text file as record
        position_type_list = (record.read().split()[10::7])  # Creates a variable named position_type_list, the records files is then read in and split. I then tell the program to start on index 10 and to skip the next 7 elements, this happens until the loop is over
        position_type = ' '.join(position_type_list)  # joins all values into a list
        position_type = (position_type.replace(',', ''))  # Replaces all the ',' with spaces
        developer = position_type.count("Developer")  # Creates a variable called developer and counts the position_type variable to see how many times the word 'Developers' appears
        print('%-40s%-0s' % ("The total number of Developers is:", developer))  # Prints out the developer variable
        devops = position_type.count("DevOps")  # Creates a variable called devops and counts the position_type variable to see how many times the word 'DevOps' appears
        print('%-40s%-0s' % ("The total number of DevOps is:", devops))  # Prints out the devops variable
        analyst = position_type.count("Analyst")  # Creates a variable called analyst and counts the position_type variable to see how many times the word 'Analyst' appears
        print('%-40s%-0s' % ("The total number of Analysts is:", analyst))  # Prints out the analyst variable
        tester = position_type.count("Tester")  # Creates a variable called analyst and counts the position_type variable to see how many times the word 'Tester' appears
        print('%-40s%-0s' % ("The total number of Testers is:", tester))  # Prints out the tester variable
        designer = position_type.count("Designer")  # Creates a variable called designer and counts the position_type variable to see how many times the word 'Designer' appears
        print('%-40s%-0s' % ("The total number of Designers is:", designer))  # Prints out the designer variable
    position_finished = input("Are you ready to return back to the menu?(yes/no): ").lower()  # Stores the user input into the position_finished variable
    if position_finished == 'yes':  # Checks the users input to see if it equal to 'yes'
        main()  # Returns the user to the main function
    else:
        average_salary()  # Returns the user to the search_for_a_record function


def above_salary_threshold():  # Creates a function called above_salary_threshold
    try:  # Tries the code for any errors
        user_threshold = int(input("Enter the salary threshold: "))  # Asks the user to input data and stores it as an integer
        for line in records:  # Creates a for loop
            fields = line.split(', ')  # Creates a variable called fields and splits the lines that have ','
            if user_threshold < int(fields[4]):  # Creates an if statement
                print('%03i\t\t%-20s£%-10.2f' % (int(fields[0]), fields[1], int(fields[4])))  # Formats the output
        above_salary_finished = input("Are you ready to return back to the menu?(yes/no): ").lower()
        if above_salary_finished == 'yes':  # Checks if the users input is equal to use
            main()  # Returns the user to the main function
        else:
            above_salary_threshold()  # Returns the user to the above_salary_threshold function
    except ValueError:  # Catches any value errors
        print("You have entered an invalid number")  # Prints a message to the user
        main()


def search_for_a_record():
    try:  # Tries the code for any errors
        data = open('Records.txt').read().splitlines()  # opens the records file and reads and splits the lines and stores it to the data variable
        emp_no = input("\nEnter the UserID you would like to search for: ")  # Creates a variable called emp_no and asks the user to enter a userID
        record = [line for line in data if line.split(',')[0] == emp_no][0]  # Creates a for loop to search through the list of records and splits them up and searches each line for the value entered in by the user
        print(record)  # Prints the records variable
        another_record = input("\nDo you want to enter another User_ID?(yes/no): ").lower()  # Stores the user input as lowercase
        if another_record == 'yes':  # Creates an IF statement to see if the user wants to search for another record, if the user selects yes the code in this section will run
            search_for_a_record()  # Returns to the beginning of the search_for_a_record function
        else:
            main()  # Returns the user to the main function
    except IndexError:  # Catches any errors
        print("\nYou have entered an invalid number")  # Prints a message to the user
        search_for_a_record()  # Returns the user to the search_for_a_record function


users_name = input("What is your name?: ")  # Asks the user for their name and stores their input to the users_name variable
print("\nWelcome", users_name)  # Prints welcome followed by the name stored in the users_name variable

main()  # calls the main function
```

Comment: Why would `total_salary` be concerned with menus? What's wrong with how things are currently set up? This should loop via a recursive call if they say they want to go back to the menu. The only major problem I see is `total_salary()` should be `print(total_salary())` if you want that to be printed.

Comment: Sorry I must not have made it clear, in the total_salary function I need the user to be able to go back to the menu as I can not have the program exiting without using the menu

Comment: It should be already going back to the menu once `total_salary` returns. And just a note, you're not going to want to call `total_salary` several times. Call it once in `average_salary`, save the return value, and use the return instead. Something like `salary = total_salary()`. Calling `total_salary` involves reading a file, so you don't want to be doing that over and over again when you don't need to.

Comment: Thank you for that information. also so when I run the total_salary function and it returns the total my program just exits, it doesn't go back to the main function that holds the menu. Any ideas on why that happens?

Comment: With the code you've posted, the only way I can see that possibly happening is if it's exiting due to an error. How are you running the code?

Comment: I am using pycharm, I will edit the post and post my entire code so maybe it will give you a better understanding

Comment: I undated my post so my whole code is there